# How to clone a Wordpress Elastic Beanstalk Environment Correctly?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a correct way of cloning an Elastic Beanstalk Environment correctly? I took over a project which contains a production environment and cloned it for the purposes of making it as the development environment. However, it points to the same url, while generating all the other resources of the production one.

When I made changes to the development env and used 'eb deploy' while pointing to it, the changes I made is not being reflected. Also the url of the production environment and dev environment points the same. How do I separate these 2 correctly so my changes on the dev can be differentiated from production.

Comment: Have you checked https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/deploying-wordpress-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk.pdf?

Comment: Thanks for that link. I'm currently reading through it and it from my initial impression though, it doesn't mention anything about cloned EB environments and configuring it to create a distinct url to serve as the dev environment. I'm fairly new to AWS but I've been looking at the settings on EB to separate it from my production env but I don't see it. Does this mean I would just delete my cloned dev environment and create one according to the guide you mentioned?

Comment: May be you shoud read about blue/green deployment,not sure.